# How to use same serializer class for get and post method in Django 4.2?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have been trying, but fail miserably, to use only a single serializer class for both post and get api call. I have a team model that has many to many relationship with the project model. I want to only use the id when am doing the post but when doing the GET request am able to view the details of the team

team model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from . import Project

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    description = models.TextField()
    members = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model())
    projects = models.ManyToManyField(Project, blank=True, related_name='teams_projects')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.name)
```

project model

```
from django.db import models
class Project(models.Model):
    PENDING = 'Pending'
    IN_PROGRESS = 'In Progress'
    COMPLETED = 'Completed'

    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (PENDING, 'Pending'),
        (IN_PROGRESS, 'In Progress'),
        (COMPLETED, 'Completed'),
    ]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    teams = models.ManyToManyField('Team', related_name='team_projects')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=PENDING)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.name)
```

serializer

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Project, Team

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'status', 'teams']
        depth = 2


class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    projects = ProjectSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ["id", "name", "description", "members", "projects"]
        # depth = 2
```

I have tried to use 'depth' but now am required provide team information instead of only id when doing the post.

POST request body

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "members": [
    0
  ],
  "projects": [
    {
      "name": "string",
      "description": "string",
      "start_date": "2023-09-29",
      "end_date": "2023-09-29",
      "status": "Pending",
      "teams": [
        0
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different field for read and write.
For example, here, I have created a field "write_teams" for using it on POST.
I have overwriten the method "create" to save this specific field.

```py
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    write_teams = serializers.IntegerField(many=True, write_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'status', 'teams', 'write_teams']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        teams = validated_data.pop('write_teams')
        project = Project(**validated_data)
        project.save()
        project.teams.set([Team(pk=x) for x in teams])
```

Comment: Was this answer helpfull ? If yes, please consider upvoting or accepting the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution to your problem is to make use of `to_represetantion()`. So your TeamSerializer should look like so:

```py
class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ["id", "name", "description", "members", "projects"]
        
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super(TeamSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        data['projects'] =  ProjectSerializer(instance.projects.all(), many=True).data
        return data
```

Comment: @BlackHawk0 you can mark it as the answer